# How to add one header in each line in http post request

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I'm making a http post request and I have to pass the username and password in the headers. 
This is how I'm doing it:

```
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear(); 

 string jsonObjectA = DataDto.ToJSONString();
 HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonObjectA, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("userName", "".AppendWebConfigValue("username"));
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("password", "".AppendWebConfigValue("Password"));

 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
 client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://url/");
 httpResponse = client.PostAsync("method/test", content).Result;
```

This is how the request should be:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
content-Type : application/json
userName: username
password: password
```

However, this is what I get when I run my code above:

```
userName:usernamepassword:passwordAccept:application/json
```

I tried adding using Environment.NewLine but it threw an error that header not in the correct format.

How can I add 2 headers each in a separate line to be able to get a response from the server?

Comment: Does adding the headers in your code not work? I know the format you posted isn't what you're saying is the desired format, but it also looks raw and un-parsed. Did you check the request on the receiving end and check the headers?

Comment: @MarkC. The headers format doesn't throw any errors but I'm getting a response code 400 and all returned data is null.

Comment: what kind of object is `client` ?

Comment: @MarkC. HttpClient

Comment: \r\n is not the problem, it must be the content you are trying to send.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpRequestMessage` to create the request and add the headers you want:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri("https://postb.in/1559160461304-0137126960325"),
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    };

    request.Headers.Add("username", "username");
    request.Headers.Add("password", "password");

    var httpResponse = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
}
```

[image]